# No Frills Magento Layout error while trying to create block

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have been following the No Frills Magento Layout book. All examples were working fine until this section:

```
http://localhost/magento/nofrills_booklayout/index/layout
```

local/Nofrills/Booklayout/etc/config.xml:

```
app/code/local/Nofrills/Booklayout/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nofrills_Booklayout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Nofrills_Booklayout>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <nofrills_booklayout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Nofrills_Booklayout</module>
                    <frontName>nofrills_booklayout</frontName>
                </args>
            </nofrills_booklayout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <nofrills_booklayout>
                <class>Nofrills_Booklayout_Block</class>
            </nofrills_booklayout>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <nofrills_booklayout>
                <class>Nofrills_Booklayout_Model</class>
            </nofrills_booklayout>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <nofrills_booklayout>
                <class>Nofrills_Booklayout_Helper</class>
            </nofrills_booklayout>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

local/Nofrills/BookLayout/Block/HelloWorld.php:

```
<?php
class Nofrills_Booklayout_Block_HelloWorld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template 
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('helloworld.phtml');
        return parent::_construct();
    }

    public function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $block_1 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text();
        $block_1->setText('The first sentence. ');
        $this->setChild('the_first', $block_1);

        $block_2 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text();
        $block_2->setText('The second sentence. ');
        $this->setChild('the_second', $block_2);
    }

    public function fetchTitle() 
    {
        return 'Hello Fancy World';
    }
}
```

local/Nofrills/Booklayout/controllers/IndexController.php:

```
public function layoutAction()
{
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('nofrills_booklayout/helloworld');
    echo $block->toHtml();
}
```

And that gives me:

```
Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in...
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but dont create block instances using `new`. I mean this is not a good idea `$block_1 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text()`. Use the factory instead. `$block1 = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')`; Do the same for $block2.

Comment: This is the book going part by part. First it shows using the classic PHP method of instantiating and then it starts to use factory method. I don't think it is the issue here.

Comment: I agree. I was just trying to point in the right directino. Here is something else I spotted. Your file name is 'HelloWorld'. With an uppercase `W`. You can either rename it to `Helloworld` or when creating an instance of it do it like this `$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('nofrills_booklayout/helloWorld');`.

Comment: That's it. Just simply converting "helloworld" to "helloWorld" it work =) Thank a million.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
public function layoutAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('nofrills_booklayout/helloworld'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Nofrills_Booklayout_IndexController::_addContent() in app/code/local/Nofrills/Booklayout/controllers/IndexController.php

Answer (score 0):

As Marius said in the comments section, changing "helloworld" to "helloWorld" make it happen.